# Const not defined in nodejs causing unit tests to fail

Tags: node.js, constants

Error that I am getting

ReferenceError: LAST_PAYMENT_AMOUNT is not defined

part of nodejs code

```
const LAST_PAYMENT_AMOUNT = [LAST_PAYMENT_AMOUNT];
const LAST_PAYMENT_DATE = [LAST_PAYMENT_DATE];
const NEXT_PAYMENT_DATE = [NEXT_PAYMENT_DATE];

const accountIntentMap = {
  payment_summary_payoff: {
    LAST_PAYMENT_AMOUNT: "lastPaymentAmount",
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Share the whole chode.

Comment: How could you possibly think `const LAST_PAYMENT_AMOUNT = [LAST_PAYMENT_AMOUNT];`  could ever work?  Your attempting to define `LAST_PAYMENT_AMOUNT`, but trying to use `LAST_PAYMENT_AMOUNT` to initialize it.  Guess what, `LAST_PAYMENT_AMOUNT` doesn't exist yet so you can't use it to initialize itself.  It also doesn't even make sense.  I'm hoping this is a typo and the value inside the array brackets it somehow a typo for all three.

Comment: So my question was what will work. I kinda know it does not work. This is my first time asking question on this site

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access: `LAST_PAYMENT_AMOUNT`, `LAST_PAYMENT_DATE` & `NEXT_PAYMENT_DATE` before initialization.

That code won't work, and doesn't make sense. You probably want to assign something different to each `const`.